# android applications activity switching on blackberry playbook

Tags: android, mobile, blackberry-playbook

I have an android application that i successfully ported to the blackberry playbook. I updated my playbook to OS 2.1 and all of a sudden, when the ported android app switches/launches a new activity, the BB OSs' "multitasking" window comes up showing all the other android applications "running" on the playbook. So i have to tap my app's window again to make it fullscreen. This happens for every activity that my app launches, and my app has about 8 activities all in all... is there anything i need to change in my app to stop this from happening on the playbook? Thanks